# Android 5.1 : Cannot install, but I can Cancel

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, installation, apk

I have a tablet named Samsung Galaxy Edge Max, I need to download and install Minecraft , and `Install` button doesn't works, while `Cancel` Button works in Android 5.1.

Comment: Do you have given permission to install apk in security Settings (Set it to Unknown Sources)

Comment: A screenshot could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any screen dimming App running? if yes its probably that this app generates a overlay and send all presses through the overlay and the Install button is protected against such clicks. Or you didn't enable the Unknown Sources in your Settings